# GKE nodes fail to upgrade (zone us-west1-b)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to upgrade nodes to 1.15.7-gke.23 and getting this error since 24.01.2020.

```
Failure in zone us-west1-b due to tight resource constraints.
You can either try again later or create another node pool in another zone and migrate workloads.
(See https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool) Recommended alternative zone: us-west1-a).
```

Current Master version: 1.15.7-gke.23
Current Node version: 1.14.7-gke.14

I don't want to migrate to different zone.
Error is on my side? Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to ServerFault! I've checked your issue on my test project and I got the same result. At first, there's no error on your side. Situation like this happened from time to time and usually it didn't take as long to add resources to zone and fix it. In my opinion, you should:

1. open a ticket at [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?q=) (more information [here](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker))
2. contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/)

I don't think you should migrate to different zone at the moment, unless you need a lot of resources urgently (have a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool) in the error message).